# enum class underlying type with forward declaration

Tags: c++, enums

I have a small enum class which I would like to forward declare in a few places. Is there a way to decouple the base type from the forward declaration? I am afraid that at some later point someone will change the type.

for example I have the enum

```
enum class e_mode : bool
{
     SYNC,
     ASYNC
};
```

the forward declaration will be:

```
enum class e_mode : bool;
```

if someone adds another value he will need to change the bool to char and then go around changing the forward declarations. I would like to avoid that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `enum`'s underlying type could be previously defined by means of `typedef`:

```
typedef bool e_mode_base_t;
```

Then, you can use this type for the `enum`'s forward declaration:

```
enum class e_mode: e_mode_base_t;
```

and for the `enum`'s definition as well:

```
enum class e_mode : e_mode_base_t
{
     SYNC,
     ASYNC
};
```

This way, you only need to modify the definition of `e_mode_base_t` when you wish to change the `enum`'s underlying type.

You could as well create a type alias by means of `using` instead of `typedef`:

```
using e_mode_base_t = bool;
```

which may be more readable.

Comment: Doesn't one need to define/forward declare `e_mode_base_t` ?

Comment: @LukaRahne it will be defined by the `typedef`.

Comment: If I understand this, and I am not wrong one will need to include `typedef` from somewhere. Question is. Can `e_mode_base_t`  be hidden, just like `e_mode` is?

Comment: No. You would just place the definition of `e_mode_base_t` in a header file with *include guards* to avoid multiple inclusion and include that header before referring to `e_mode_base_t`.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a ".h" file that defines only forward declaration of enum. Insted of forward declaring enum, you then include this "cheap" h file.